# Editing cursor data before display

Tags: android, exception, android-cursoradapter

I'm new in android and Java world and I want to edit cursor data result before displaying it. To do so I wrote the following code

```
private static final String[] INTERNAL_COLUMNS_1 = new String[] {
    MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE};

private static final String[] INTERNAL_COLUMNS_2 = new String[] {
    MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, "fixString(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + ")"};

private Cursor getInternals() {
    return query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, INTERNAL_COLUMNS_1,
            constructBooleanTrueWhereClause(mFilterColumns),
            null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
}

private Cursor mCursor = new SortCursor(getInternals());

 public String fixString(String oldstr)
{

    String str = new String(oldstr);
    str = str.replace("_", " ");
    if (Character.isLowerCase(str.charAt(0)))
    {
        str = str.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1,str.length());
    }
    for(int i=1;i<str.length();i++)
    {
     if ((Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i))) 
     && (Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i)))
     && (Character.isLowerCase(str.charAt(i - 1))) 
     && (Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i - 1))))
        {
            str = str.substring(0,i) + " " + str.substring(i,str.length());
        }   
    }
    return str;
}

public static void main(){
  for (int i = 0; i < mCursor.getCount(); i++) 
    {
        mCursor.moveToPosition(i);
        String string = mCursor.getString(1);
        Log.d("OUT"," string = "+ string);
    }
```

Using **INTERNAL_COLUMNS_1**, the log shows

```
TomSkinner
Jack_Smith
foxRayan
```

I want to have as the cursor result :

```
Tom Skinner
Jack Smith
Fox Rayan
```

So I used **INTERNAL_COLUMNS_2**, but I have exception

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such function: fixString
```

Does any one know how to do so, or any other idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either change the data before it gets into the database, or change it before you display it.  What you are trying to do is create a function and use it in a SQLite query, which will not work.  Removing the `fixString` parts from the SQL query and then using it on the string from the cursor is one way it will work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < mCursor.getCount(); i++) 
    {
        mCursor.moveToPosition(i);
        String string = mCursor.getString(1);
        Log.d("OUT"," string = "+ fixString(string));
    }
```

Comment: Yes I know it'is working. But I want to have string fixed in the cursor. I can't change database values. I have an array adapter attached to the cursor that displays strings in bad format, and I want it to display it using fixString function

Comment: I saw this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587940/editing-cursor-data-before-listadapter-displays-it-in-the-listview and I tried to do the same with my fixString function